# Parse a string into a net.Addr

Tags: go

How this can be done? I would like to know how to parse a string into a net.Addr in Go. As I see there are only parsers for CIDR, IP, and MAC.

Comment: `net.Addr` is an interface and could be many types.  Are you looking for `ParseIP`?

Comment: I am looking for ```net.Addr``` because it is used with UDP connections along with the ```WriteTo``` method.

Comment: @thwd can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the net.Resolve* functions to parse addresses. The functions return values that satisfy the [net.Addr](https://godoc.org/net#Addr) interface.

The [net.ResolveIPAddr](https://godoc.org/net#ResolveIPAddr) function parses the address for an IP endpoint:

```
 ip, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", "203.0.113.0")
 if err != nil {
      // handle error
 }
```

Use [net.ResolveUPDAddr](https://godoc.org/net#ResolveUDPAddr) to parse the address of a UDP endpoint (the scenario mentioned in the question comments). The addresss of a UDP endpoint is an IP endpoint and port.

```
 ip, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "203.0.113.0:53")
 if err != nil {
      // handle error
 }
```

The variables `ip` in the snippets above are typed to the specific address type, but can be used anywhere a `net.Addr` is needed.

Comment: Also if someone finds this, please try ```udp``` instead ```ip``` in the first argument if nothing else works.

Comment: Same here. Had to use "udp" instead of "ip" for net.ResolveUDPAddr

Answer (score 3):

Use `net.ResolveIPAddr`

```golang
var ip net.Addr

ip, _ = net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", "1.1.1.1")
```